# Repeating staggered animation sequence using CSS only

Tags: html, css, animation

#### Infinite diagonal flip animation with disappearing squares in a 4x4 grid

I'm creating an animation with a 4x4 grid of squares that flip diagonally one by one. Here's what I've achieved so far:

1. The squares flip individually as desired.
2. After two squares are clicked, they disappear.
3. Once the other two squares are clicked, the entire 4x4 grid disappears.

**Challenge:** I want the animation to **loop infinitely**, with the following sequence:

1. Show all 4 squares.
2. Flip tiles 1 and 4 diagonally (clockwise), then hide them after a delay.
3. Repeat steps 2 and 3 for tiles 2 and 3.
4. After all squares are hidden, **show all squares unflipped again** and restart the sequence.

**Question:** How can I implement this infinite loop functionality with disappearing squares in my animation? As mentioned in the title, I don't want to use JavaScript and would love to know if this is possible with CSS only.

Below is the code I have.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  background-color: rgb(19, 18, 18);
}

@keyframes tileFlipShow {
  from {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: visible;
  }
}

@keyframes tileFlipHide {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: visible;
  }
  to {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@keyframes hideTile {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.tile-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  max-width: fit-content;
}

.tile-grid>div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

.tile-grid>div:nth-child(1) .flip-card-inner {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.tile-grid>div:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

.tile-grid>div:nth-child(4) .flip-card-inner {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.tile-grid>div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3.5s;
}

.tile-grid>div:nth-child(2) .flip-card-inner {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.tile-grid>div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 3.5s;
}

.tile-grid>div:nth-child(3) .flip-card-inner {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.flip-card {
  perspective: 1000px;
  margin: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 9.375rem;
  width: 9.375rem;
  min-width: 3.125rem;
  min-height: 3.125rem;
  max-height: 9.375rem;
  max-width: 9.375rem;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  animation: 0.5s hideTile both;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  animation: 0.5s tileFlipShow both;
}

.flip-card-front {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.flip-card-front * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.flip-card-back {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffc796 0%, #ff6b95 100%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10rem);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flip-card-back * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.flip-card-back img {
  width: auto;
  height: 90%;
}

.flip-card-back picture {
  width: auto;
  height: 90%;
}

.flip-card-matched {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-counter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 5 example</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="tile-grid">
        <div class="flip-card">
          <div class="flip-card-inner not-matched">
            <div class="flip-card-front">1</div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">11</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card">
          <div class="flip-card-inner not-matched">
            <div class="flip-card-front">2</div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">22</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card">
          <div class="flip-card-inner not-matched">
            <div class="flip-card-front">3</div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">22</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card">
          <div class="flip-card-inner not-matched">
            <div class="flip-card-front">4</div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">11</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you make a separate animation for each box and have each animation last the duration of the entire sequence but be mostly nothing then set them all to repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created new keyframes for each square using your original animation delays as a basis following this timeline:

```
animation start
0   (0%)     card 1 flip start
0.5 (10%)    card 1 flip end
1   (20%)    card 4 flip start
1.5 (30%)    card 4 flip end, card 1+4 fade out start
2   (40%)    card 1+4 fade out end, card 2 flip start
2.5 (50%)    card 2 flip end
3   (60%)    card 3 flip start
3.5 (70%)    card 3 flip end, card 2+3 fade out start
4   (79.99%) card 2+3 fade out end, card 1+2+3+4 unflip start
4   (80%)    card 1+2+3+4 unflip end, card 1+2+3+4 fade in start
4.5 (90%)    card 1+2+3+4 fade in end
5   (100%)   wait after cards fade back in before looping
animation end
```

The keyframes are structured like so:

```css
@keyframes flip_1 {
  0% { /* flip start */
    transform: none;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  10%, /* flip end */
  79.99% { /* unflip start */
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: visible;
  }
  80% { /* unflip end */
    transform: none;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@keyframes fade_1_4 {
  30% { /* fade out start */
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40%, /* fade out end */
  80% { /* fade in start */
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% { /* fade in end */
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

I then set `animation-duration: 5s;` and `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` on both `.flip-card` and `.flip-card-inner`.

If you'd prefer the animation to behave differently, let me know and I'll update my answer.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  background-color: rgb(19, 18, 18);
}

@keyframes flip_1 {
  0% {
    transform: none;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  10%,
  79.99% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: visible;
  }
  80% {
    transform: none;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@keyframes flip_4 {
  20% {
    transform: none;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  30%,
  79.99% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: visible;
  }
  80% {
    transform: none;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@keyframes fade_1_4 {
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40%,
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes flip_2 {
  40% {
    transform: none;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  50%,
  79.99% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: visible;
  }
  80% {
    transform: none;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@keyframes flip_3 {
  60% {
    transform: none;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  70%,
  79.99% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: visible;
  }
  80% {
    transform: none;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@keyframes fade_2_3 {
  70% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  79.99%,
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.tile-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  max-width: fit-content;
}

.flip-card:nth-child(1) .flip-card-inner {
  animation-name: flip_1;
}

.flip-card:nth-child(4) .flip-card-inner {
  animation-name: flip_4;
}

.flip-card:nth-child(1), .flip-card:nth-child(4) {
  animation-name: fade_1_4;
}

.flip-card:nth-child(2) .flip-card-inner {
  animation-name: flip_2;
}

.flip-card:nth-child(3) .flip-card-inner {
  animation-name: flip_3;
}

.flip-card:nth-child(2), .flip-card:nth-child(3) {
  animation-name: fade_2_3;
}

.flip-card {
  perspective: 1000px;
  margin: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 9.375rem;
  width: 9.375rem;
  min-width: 3.125rem;
  min-height: 3.125rem;
  max-height: 9.375rem;
  max-width: 9.375rem;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.flip-card-front {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.flip-card-front * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.flip-card-back {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffc796 0%, #ff6b95 100%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10rem);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flip-card-back * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.flip-card-back img {
  width: auto;
  height: 90%;
}

.flip-card-back picture {
  width: auto;
  height: 90%;
}

.flip-card-matched {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-counter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 5 example</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="tile-grid">
        <div class="flip-card">
          <div class="flip-card-inner not-matched">
            <div class="flip-card-front">1</div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">11</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card">
          <div class="flip-card-inner not-matched">
            <div class="flip-card-front">2</div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">22</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card">
          <div class="flip-card-inner not-matched">
            <div class="flip-card-front">3</div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">22</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card">
          <div class="flip-card-inner not-matched">
            <div class="flip-card-front">4</div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">11</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for this. I was creating a memory game as part of learning Blazor. This was for the loading screen. Will post the link once it is ready. 

I wanted an animated pointer to do the clicks. Let me try and modify the code to do that.

Comment: Here is the link to the game I created which starts with the above loading animaiton.
https://kannansuresh.github.io/ClickMatch